# The Writer is closed or in error state

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

While calling `XslCompiledTransform.Transform()` method I get this exception :

> The Writer is closed or in error state.

Anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that...The Writer is closed or in error state.

Show us the surrouding code.  It looks like you have a StreamWriter associated with that object that has been disposed or threw an error.  For example:

```
using( var stream = new SomeStream() )
using( var streamWriter = new StreamWriter() )
{
    someObj.SomeStreamWriter = streamWriter;
    // ...
}

// should throw an error as streamWriter
// has been disposed of by this point.
someObj.WriteToStream();
```

Comment: @AJP: No problem, glad to help.  I assume that the stream was closed/disposed then?